# Is overloading in inheritance class possible in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading

Is overloading in inheritance class possible in Java? Parent class and Child class contain the same method name, but different parameters. Is this overloading?

```java
class Parent {
    public void add(int a) {
        System.out.println("I am parent" + a);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public void add(long a) {
        System.out.println("I am child.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to call `Child c = new Child(); c.add(1); c.add(1L);` ? You already have everything to discover the answer yourself. And then, do the same with `Parent p = new Child(); p.add(1); p.add(1L);`

Comment: Yes, this is overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. While extending any class, internally it means all accessible behaviour of the parent class will be present or inherited in child class. i.e, so in your case same name with different argument is overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, overloading in inheritance class is possible in Java. Java compiler detect that add method has multiple implementations. so according to the parameter java compiler will determines which method has to be executed.

```
class Parent {
    public void add(int a) {
        System.out.println("I am parent " + a);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public void add(long a) {
        System.out.println("I am child.");
    }
}
class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){

    Child child = new Child();
    child.add(1); // prints "I am parent 1"
    child.add(1L); // prints "I am child."

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In java allow overloading concept which means you can declare different method with Same name and different parameter .In your case You are extending the parent class ,which means all the property of parent class available in child class(child).

Its a overloading:

```
Child c = new Child(); 
c.add(1);//it will call the parent method
c.add(1L);//It will call the child method
```